# Re-initialized state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a complex component with some "dynamic" imports.

I recreate my component tree on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-rosalind-t3cfm?file=/src/App.js:298-302

I have an `App.js` file where I have a list of objects. Each object, render a `RenderWidget` component.

Inside `RenderWidget`, I need to get a "dynamic" comp. (I recreated that with a simple function, but i have more complexity in that part). So I wrapped the comp on useMemo to avoid component re-creation. (useMemo has a console.log to check if the `Comp` is re-initializated)

Inside the `Comp`, we have a useState declaration with the following initial value:

```
const getData = () => {
   console.log("getData called");
   return Math.random();
 };

const [data, setData] = useState(getData());
```

If You click on H1, we force an update on App.js. If you check the console, You get "getData called" each time that you click on H1.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer!

For the "lazy" initial value, we need to call the function like this:

```
// Replace that
const [data, setData] = useState(getData());

// With that
const [data, setData] = useState(() => getData());
```

Answer (score 1):

If parent component props have changed it will re-render all of its children, you can use `React.memo` to prevent unnecessary re-render.

I also suggest you to read this [article](https://overreacted.io/before-you-memo/), it's written by the author of the react core team,
in addition to memo, there are other ways to prevent re-rendering

```
export default memo(function RenderWidget() {
  const LocalComp = useMemo(() => {
    console.log("NO RE-INITIALIZED");
    return getComp();
  }, []);

  return <LocalComp />;
});
```